# Re-Structuring ClearCase Multi-site Projects Issues

Tags: clearcase

I have a ClearCase UCM VOB with over 50 UML modeling project streams. I want to restructure the package structures of all the projects with the minimum disruption to ongoing development. Because of the number of projects, the time element could be substantial so numerous changes could occur during the process.

The approach I am considering is to create a full branch at the root, restructure the branch, have the original branch projects one by one deliver to the root and rebase the new branch after each project delivery and have the project create a new project stream using the new rebased branch.

Is there a better way? Has anyone experienced issues with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The neat thing with ClearCase is that you can  move / rename directories without loosing their history.
And the next merge between an original content (before refactoring) and the new content *should* work correctly.

What you need is a dedicated Stream in each of your project, for refactoring purpose.
On each Stream, you would rebase it with the latest baseline available in your UCM project, and then perform your refactoring in it.

Pending the date where everybody is ready to use the new code organization, you can make several other deliver from a Stream with the old content to your refactoring dedicated Stream, and put a Baseline on the refactoring Stream after each deliver.

But I would recommend, to avoid any confusion, to make 50 new UCM projects, with an integration Stream based on the latest refactoring baseline available from the old UCM project.
That way, you can start again your hierarchy of Stream based only on refactored content.